# Can't use shortcut(shift+print) but command(gnome-screenshot -a) of area screenshot

Tags: screenshot, linux-mint

**~/.xscreen-errors**

> ** Message: Unable to use GNOME Shell's builtin screenshot interface, resorting to fallback X11.
>
> (gnome-screenshot:30803): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_from_surface: assertion 'width > 0 && height > 0' failed
>
> (gnome-screenshot:30803): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_window_resize: assertion 'width > 0' failed
>
> ** (gnome-screenshot:30803): CRITICAL **: Unable to capture a screenshot of any window

I'm using Linux Mint 17.1 `Cinamon` 64-bit and this problem appears after upgrading from 17.0 to 17.1.

Comment: To be specific, I can use `gnome-screenshot` and `gnome-screen -w` both by command and shortcut. But for `gnome-screenshot -a` I can't use the shortcut `shift+print`.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191973/how-to-create-custom-shortcuts-for-scrot-and-gnome-screenshot-interactive-mode , I have similar problem like you, try to set up a agent/middle shortcut key to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

your just Enter the keyword is 'PrtScr'